# jquery ajax modify data response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost/apsd4/core/main_quota.html',
  success: function(data) {
        $('#tabs-2').html(r);
        $('#tabs-2 #nini').remove();            
  }
});
```

I would like to change data response before echo data 
Stages:

1. remove '#tabs-2 #nini'
2. html()

Comment: Can you make your question more clear please?

Comment: Wow, this is 'ununderstandable'. Please explain better

Comment: So you want to add the response to `#tabs-2` *but* remove the `#nini` element (in the response) first?

Answer (score 0):

I think as what I understand on your problem, you wanted to improve your $.ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/apsd4/core/main_quota.html",
    success: function(result) {

        $('#tabs-2').html(data).find('#nini').remove();
        // do some code here

    }
});
```

Comment: thanks but 1.load all after remove but i am remove #nini after echo data